# i made CEGUI-0.8.2 by cmake and then trying add ogre3d, but have some problems help me

Tags: ogre3d, cegui

this is my first time for cegui, maybe this problems are sounds like stupid, but i dont why really.

im doing now compile the cegui vs_solution, but there are some compile error.

i already ogre-sdk-1.8.1ver and cegui-0.8.2 vs_solution made by cmake.

here is error_code,

error C1083: cannot open files 'boost/thread/tss.hpp': No such file or directory    c:\ogresdk_vc10_v1-8-1\include\ogre\threading\OgreThreadHeadersBoost.h  37
.....

in OgreThreadHeadersBoots.h

source code is

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
This source file is a part of OGRE
(Object-oriented Graphics Rendering Engine)

For the latest info, see http://www.ogre3d.org/

Copyright (c) 2000-2012 Torus Knot Software Ltd
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#ifndef __OgreThreadHeadersBoost_H__
#define __OgreThreadHeadersBoost_H__

#if OGRE_COMPILER == OGRE_COMPILER_CLANG || OGRE_COMPILER == OGRE_COMPILER_GCC
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wshadow"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpadded"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wweak-vtables"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
#endif

#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>   //this code makes error    
#include <boost/thread/recursive_mutex.hpp> //this code makes error
#include <boost/thread/condition.hpp> //this code makes error
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp> //this code makes error
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp> //this code makes error
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp> //this code makes error

#if OGRE_COMPILER == OGRE_COMPILER_CLANG || OGRE_COMPILER == OGRE_COMPILER_GCC
#   pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif

#endif
```

i tryed add include path C:\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-8-1;$(IncludePath) or C:\OgreSDK_vc10_v1-8-1\include\OGRE or blahblah possible path everyting i think :(

if anybody know this problem plz advise to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to include `"c:\ogresdk_vc10_v1-8-1\boost"` This should fix your problem. You might also need to add `"c:\ogresdk_vc10_v1-8-1\boost\lib"` in your additional libraries.

Comment: yeah you are right :) it is already added "boost_1.42_lib" like this , so i missed that you advised. thanks :)